# using Iterator is a performance hit?

Tags: java, java-8

Im hearing many people saying do to use Iterator while using loops instead use access-by-index...but im not able to get the proper justification..

Any explanation with an example helps!!!

I mean instead of the below

```
for (String value : strings) {
    // Do something useful here
}
```

use

```
int size = strings.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String value : strings.get(i);
    // Do something useful here
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the time complexity of `List.get(i)` for a general list? 2) How do you use index-based iteration with a `Collection` that doesn't support index-based access, e.g. `Set`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you look at those two examples, which one do you think looks better/clearer/etc ?

Comment: Need speed? Make it `String[] strings` and iterate over that. You can't beat arrays. But you probably don't need that kind of speed difference.

Comment: @Disco first looks more legible but     "Iterators, Iterable, and the foreach loop are extremely useful from a writeability and readability perspective, as well as from an API design perspective. However, they create a small new instance on the heap for each single iteration. If you run this iteration many many times, you want to make sure to avoid creating this useless instance, and write index-based iterations instead."   reference http://blog.jooq.org/2015/02/05/top-10-easy-performance-optimisations-in-java/

Comment: @shiv455 - I was just curious you didn't mention it and wondered if you'd considered it.

Comment: Don't even waste a minute worrying about it.  If what you're doing is so ultra-performance-sensitive that this would make a difference, you'd know it.